# Cypher : Match on a relation who match another relation

Tags: database, neo4j, request, cypher, relation

I would to know how in Cypher can we write something like :
I want all : `r:Application___Flux who have r:Flux___Application`

Clearly I would like to know if we can apply a relationship on an Inclusion
[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pppDS.png)

Comment: MATCH p=()-[r:Application___Flux]-()-[e:Flux___Application]-() RETURN p

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using `p`? You can simply return `r` and `e`.

Comment: @Philigane please never add question information as a comment.  Always edit your question to include additional details so that readers don't have to comb through all of the comments to understand the full story.  After editing, delete your comment.